# Insert missing records from table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `users` *(id, username, etc...)* and `user_contacts` *(id, userid, contactid, etc...)*.

Given that I have a `user` w/ an id of 84, what would be the most efficient query in order to have missing records inserted into `user_contacts` to associate `user` 84 w/ all other users?

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you mean that you want to add every other users as contacts of user `84`?

Comment: @plalx correct. I want user 84 to be listed as a contact for all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your most recent comment, then this should work:

```
insert into user_contacts (userid, contactid)
select u.id, 84
from users u 
   left join user_contacts uc on u.id = uc.userid and uc.contactid = 84
where uc.id is null
```

This will insert a row into the user_contacts table for each user who currently don't have a row with contactid 84.  Be sure to specify your columns correctly.

Alternatively, you could use `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`.  For example,

```
insert into user_contacts (userid, contactid)
select u.id, 84
from users u
where u.id not in (
    select userid 
    from user_contacts 
    where contactid = 84)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly and only takes around ~.15 seconds to complete

Comment: @KyleDecot -- np, glad I could help!